# AWS LightSail Update Launch Script

Tags: amazon-lightsail

Can I use AWS Lightsail's Launch Script option to upgrade Wordpress/LAMP upon creation?

Lightsail saves time and ports to EC2 if needed. 
Sadly, it loads an old versions of wordpress and LAMP.
The option to add a launch script when creating a new instance would seem an ideal way to create an up to date site. A fresh instance followed by a simple site migration would save hours of updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you can script the upgrade, you can use the launch script. But, I'd argue that's not the best way to solve the problem.

Bitnami images use a different directory structure than a "normal" WordPress installation, so getting all that correct could be a hassle.

It would likely be faster to just boot an Ubuntu (or whatever) image and use the launch script to install the Apache, PHP, and WordPress versions you want.